# Voltage regulator up to 100v?

Tags: power-supply, power, voltage, voltage-regulator

I want to make a power supply that outputs 90v DC, and I was looking for a 0...100v voltage regulators, but I don't find any...? How can I achieve this if I can't find them? The input voltage of the circuit would be 220V 50Hz.

EDIT: I have 220v to 110v 5A transformer although is really big.

Comment: A voltage regulator will not turn AC into DC and if you use a diode or bridge and cap to turn 220V into filtered DC you'll get about 310VDC. Please tell us what you are trying to do- this approach seems fraught with difficulties.

Comment: i know i need the bridge, what i'm trying to do is to replace de lm317 voltage regulation design to something with more voltage, i need at least 130W and the lm317 is limited to something like 37V regulation

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, what level of regulation do you need? And do you have the knowledge level to work with this voltage level?

Comment: well, i need to have 90VDC fixed voltage, actually i don't need the regulation at all, so i was looking if i could achieve this with regulation, since there're not many diagrams to get 90v out there. indeed i just need the voltage, i'm replacing an old power supply, and i'm working with an expert, but as for now i'm researching. thanks

Comment: There are multiple sources on the web (never mind books) that will teach you how to design a simple AC-DC *converter*; it's not called a regulator. Since you appear confused about a lot of thing, maybe you should also tell us what you intend to power with it...

Comment: Google "op-amp controlled linear power supply."  Just be sure to heatsink the MOSFET. And be sure your expert is watching you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't need regulation at all, what you probably want is a transformer with about a 63VAC output. Full wave bridge module (easily available up to 35A or more) and a filter cap (value depends on ripple you can live with, but usually 100V or better) and you're done.

As an added advantage, the galvanic isolation provided by the transformer reduces the chances you will injure yourself. In any case, have a qualified electrician have a look at it before you power it up. Reversing the capacitor, for example, could lead to a bang with shrapnel and liberated electrolyte chemicals in the air.

Comment: yes, i've found a diagram that works with a 62VAC using 220v, but in this country i won't find that transformer.

Comment: You can use multiple transformers to make up the approximate voltage. 48V + 12V, for example.

Comment: what happens with the current? i just need 1.5A, so they need to have the same current limit or what?

Comment: Ohms law. The current flowing through the transformers will be proportional to the ratio of voltages across each transformer. So, if you have a transformer on a 220:100 ratio, pulling 1.5A on the secondary side will pull 1.5*(100/220) = 0.69A. If you're always stepping the voltage down, your maximum current will be reached at the final secondary, and as such you'll be within ratings if you stick to that current across all your transformers.

Comment: Each transformer needs to be rated at minimum 2.5A on the secondary to get 1.5A DC out of the rectifier/filter. Higher is no problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a linear regulator for this application.  You would burn over 250W in the regulator!  A switching power supply is needed for this application.

**Safety Notice**

Please do not take this the wrong way, but the fact that you are talking about a linear regulator at this power level concerns me.  Switching power supplies at these power levels can be very dangerous to the untrained.  When they fail at these energy levels, parts can literally explode.  Burns, fire, eye damage are all possible.

I *strongly* suggest considering purchasing something that solves your problem.

Comment: i see i can't use them, i was just using the lm317 as an example since i don't know any other way to achieve such an specific voltage, i will search for the switching power supply, and please don't worry, i'm with an expert, he's busy now haha :3